# Apache redirect to same subdomain?

Tags: apache2

I have an application running on the 8080 port on tomcat.And it works fine with this VirtualHost config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin administration@subdomain.domain.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html
     ServerName www.subdomain.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.domain.com *.subdomain.domain.com
     ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/subdomain.d/subdomain_er.log
     CustomLog /var/log/apache2/subdomain.d/subdomain_requests.log custom

     Redirect / https://subdomain.domain.es

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I have a new server and a new application that filters the "subdomain"  and loads diferent htmls and diferent style sheets depending on the subdomain name(subdomain is created by diferent comapnies that specify their own styles).

Is it possible to get the subdomain name and redirect to the same subdomain using https? Something like ServerName *.domain.com and redirect to whatever the subdomain is(*.domain.com)? Store it in a variable ?

I went through macro but macro need the parameters to be passed to it.I don't know what parameters are going to enter in the request it may be company1 it may be company2...

Comment: So you mean if someone enters `dan.domain.com` it should redirect to `https://dan.domain.es`? or do you wan to redirect `*.dan.domain.com` to `https://dan.domain.com`?

Comment: @Dan I want to redirect dan.domain.com to https://dan.domain.es and if it is valerie5 it needs to go to https://valerie5.domain.es . The subdomain can't be defined in a static way and that is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module of Apache.

First, make sure it is enabled in Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

If you add the following configuration to your virtual host, any subdomain of `domain.com` will be redirected to a subdomain of `domain.es`.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1.domain.es/$1 [R=301,L]
```

#### Explanation:

1. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$`

   This condition will look into if the host matches the pattern *.domain.com and store what was matched with `(.+)` (i.e. the subdomain). For example, the pattern `domain.com` will not match, while the following patterns will match:

   - `dan.domain.com`
   - `www.dan.domain.com`
2. `RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%1.domain.es/$1 [R=301,L]`

   This rule instructs Apache to redirect to a subdomain of `domain.es`. `%1` contains the value matched in the previous `RewriteCond` directive. While `$1` contains the value matched in this directive so you can keep the path as is and not redirect to the root of the domain.

#### Examples:

- `dan.domain.com` will redirect to `https://dan.domain.es`
- `www.dan.domain.com` will redirect to `https://www.dan.domain.es`
- `dan.domain.com/example` will redirect to `https://dan.domain.es/example`
- `www.dan.domain.com/example` will redirect to `https://www.dan.domain.es/example`